# What is the best way to extrude edges along the axis they're facing?

Tags: extrude, axis

I am trying to make a basic X shape. I am wondering the easiest, most efficient way to do that.

[image]

I want to extrude the edges along normals like I would with faces or have the edges snap to the axis as I am extruding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do that with a flat mesh, what you can do though is extrude your face up, select 4 side faces, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> >  *Extrude Faces Along Normals* or *Extrude Individual Faces*:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm going to do, it makes the most sense!